# Microsoft Edge blocking Firefox

Tags: windows-8, firefox, windows-10

I need to uninstall Microsoft Edge as it is blocking me from having access to Firefox, removed it and my bookmarks from my access.

When I tried to download a new copy of Firefox via the "ask" search engine on Edge it would not download.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to 'nuke' edge to install firefox.

You can get it installed and made default in 3 easy steps

1. Download the latest [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) here
2. Start firefox - it should prompt you to set it as default - Follow what happens, and pick firefox as your default
3. Else, Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Default Programs` (use <kbd>win</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> or paste that into explorer. Find firefox, and select "set as default"

That should make firefox your default and not fire up edge automatically.